# Why is my attempt to create a chart returning null?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

In my `ScreenFragment` class:

```
Activity parentActivity; 
public LineChart chart;  // changing private to public didn't help
```

In its `onCreate()`:

```
parentActivity = getActivity();
```

In its `onCreateView()`:

```
chart = (LineChart) parentActivity.findViewById( R.id.chart_id );
```

which is returning `null`. The ID is defined in the Fragment's XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
     tools:context="io.aeroscope.aeroscope.ScreenFragment"> 
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Why the null? Why isn't the chart being instantiated?

Comment: What is the code for your LineChart class? Do you have a default no argument constructor?

Comment: The LineChart class is part of the MPAndroidChart package. This is my first attempt at using it.

Comment: Everything looks great for a first try, except that the grid line along the very bottom of the chart isn't being drawn. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're finding the view in parent activity instead of fragment view.

It should be

```
onCreateView() {
View view = inflator.inflate(....);
chart = (LineChart) view.findViewById( R.id.chart_id );
return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was sure I read somewhere that since Views are found by ID, they could be defined (and found) anywhere. Apparently not.